# What is wrong with this deserialization? Keep getting error trying to deserialize the response file

Tags: c#, asp.net, json.net, jsonparser

What is wrong with this deserialization of my response file?
I Keep getting exception when I am trying to deserialize the response file to my model that I created.
When I try to put the response json in a file and run the deserialize it works fine. But when I am trying to convert the result it keeps failing.
What am I doing wrong?

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(URL+pg.urlParameters).Result;  
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{

    var result = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var detailsList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result.ToString());
```

I get an exception as
Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: S. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

[image: Image of the above JSON]

Comment: could you include the raw json? (after you checked its validity) - also: why are you calling `ToString()` on a `Task<string>` instead of `await`ing it?

Comment: @FranzGleichmann thank you. Feel so silly to have done that goof up

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your JSON as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing code that reproduces the problem would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to put the 'await' keyword. So your result is a Task and not the actual result yet. This should fix it:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {

        var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        var detailsList = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(result);
```